# RowSource Query Hiding Column? Syntax Issues

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

Okay, I am just forging ahead with Access VBA and I'm having a little bit of difficulty with a query that I'm having populated in a ListBox: [lboBinsOnSite]

```
'Me.lboBinsOnSite.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"'

'Me.lboBinsOnSite.RowSource = "SELECT tblBins.BinID, tblBins.BinLocationID, tblBinTypes.BinType, tblBins.BinSize " '& _'
    '"FROM tblBins " & _
    '"INNER JOIN tblBinTypes ON tblBins.BinTypeID = tblBinTypes.BinTypeID " & _'
    '"WHERE BinLocationID = '" & [LocationID] & "'"'
```

This Works perfectly (the right records are shown) BUT for some reason the three columns that are populated are BinLocationID, tblBinTYpes.BinTypeID and BinSize

BUT this query works perfectly (I just don't know how to deal with the extra parentheses (I'm sure it's syntax I'm having issues with):

```
SELECT tblBins.BinID, tblBinTypes.BinType, tblBins.BinSize FROM tblBins 
INNER JOIN tblBinTypes ON tblBins.BinTypeID = tblBinTypes.BinTypeID 
WHERE (((tblBins.BinLocationID)="ABBY-01"));
```

What I want is instead of ABBY-01 to have `[LocationID]` be the variable it looks up (but it's a hidden column and I don't need it to be displayed).

Any ideas?

Comment: I added another 'tblBins.BinID,' to SELECT and it works now. Not sure why it needs to be repeated though. Would love an explanation! 

`code' Me.lboBinsOnSite.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
'Me.lboBinsOnSite.RowSource = "SELECT tblBins.BinID, tblBins.BinID, tblBinTypes.BinType, tblBins.BinSize " & _
                             "FROM tblBins " & _
                             "INNER JOIN tblBinTypes ON tblBins.BinTypeID = tblBinTypes.BinTypeID " & _'
                             "WHERE BinLocationID = '" & [LocationID] & "'"`code'

Answer (score 0):

It was simply a syntax issue. Working backwards solved it.